# Display Rss feed according to Date and Time?

Tags: android, date, time, xml-parsing, rss

I am working on RSS Reader for a website but when i retrive the RSS feed it is not according to Date and Time, Please check the Screen Shot. Can some one please help me by showing me how to show the latest feed in my app.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9pgbnwazorncnl/20150514233219%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0

Here is my code :

```
public class NewsFeedParser {
    private InputStream urlStream;
    private XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    private XmlPullParser parser;
    private List<RSSFeed> rssFeedList;
    private RSSFeed rssFeed;
    private String urlString;
    private String tagName;
    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String description;
    private String category;
    private String pubDate;
    private String guid;
    private String feedburner;
    public static final String ITEM = "item";
    public static final String CHANNEL = "channel";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String LINK = "link";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String CATEGORY = "category";
    public static final String PUBLISHEDDATE = "pubDate";
    public static final String GUID = "guid";
    public static final String FEEDBURNERORIGLINK = "feedburner:origLink";
    public NewsFeedParser(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }
    public static InputStream downloadStream(String urlString) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        return stream;
    }
    public List<RSSFeed> parseXmlData() {
        try {
            int count = 0;
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            parser = factory.newPullParser();
            urlStream = downloadStream(urlString);
            parser.setInput(urlStream, null);
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            boolean done = false;
            rssFeed = new RSSFeed();
            rssFeedList = new ArrayList<RSSFeed>();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
                tagName = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                            rssFeed = new RSSFeed();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(TITLE)) {
                            title = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(LINK)) {
                            link = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(DESCRIPTION)) {
                            description = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(CATEGORY)) {
                            category = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(PUBLISHEDDATE)) {
                            pubDate = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(GUID)) {
                            guid = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        if (tagName.equals(FEEDBURNERORIGLINK)) {
                            feedburner = parser.nextText().toString();
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagName.equals(CHANNEL)) {
                            done = true;
                        } else if (tagName.equals(ITEM)) {
                            rssFeed = new RSSFeed(title, link, description, category, pubDate,
                                    guid,
                                    feedburner);
                            Log.i("RSSFeedItem", title + " " + link + " " + description + " " + category + " " + pubDate + guid + " " + feedburner);
                            rssFeedList.add(rssFeed);

                        }
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("RSSCount", " : "+Integer.toString(rssFeedList.size()).toString());
        return rssFeedList;
    }
}
```

Comment: sort your data according to date before passing it to adapter.

Comment: Can you please explain?? Sorry I am newbie.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: Your question is broad. It will be better if you show some codes so that we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for everyone comment i am trying to sort it out by Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<Date>(){
           public int compare(Date date1, Date date2){
          return date1.after(date2);
        }
      });   But it is giving me the error  incompatiable types requires int Found Boolean.

Comment: @Egor I have added the code :) Any help is apperciated

Comment: @Kunu I have added the code :) Any help is apperciated

Comment: Can you post your `RSSFeed` class. And check you have correct Date format or not.

Comment: @Kunu Here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/po1j2lgnnk0t68o/rss.txt?dl=0

Comment: Better post your code in question rather than in a link. Check my answer, it might help you. If you are not getting your date value in Date format then first you need to change it to Date format before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class in your RSSFeed class

```
    //Shorting data w.r.t weight in descending order
    public static class DateComparator implements Comparator<RSSFeed> {
        public int compare(RSSFeed r1, RSSFeed r2) {
            Date date1 = r1.getDate();
            Date date2 = r2.getDate();

            return date1.compareTo(date2);
        }
    }
```

And use this in your listview class before passing to adapter

```
Collections.sort(yourDataList, Collections.reverseOrder(new RSSFeed.DateComparator ()));
```

Comment: when i use this , i can only see 2 list items in my feed,